# How to update the value of radio button?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a student academic details which I want to update . I successfully update some values (i.e fullname,email) but I also want to update the value of the gender which I gets from radio button element of form . I am unable to retrieve the value of gender which is stored first time in db .
Here is my preload code
In this code I try with data.gender but it not fetching gender value

```
const preload = (studentId) => {
getStudent(studentId).then((data) => {
  if (data.error) {
    setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
  } else {
    preloadFaculties();
    setValues({
      ...values,
      fullName: data.fullName,
      admissionNumber: data.admissionNumber,
      rollNumber: data.rollNumber,
      age: data.age,
      gender: data.gender,
      faculty: data.faculty,
      email: data.email,
      formData: new FormData(),
    });
  }
});
```

};

updation code

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
setValues({ ...values, error: "", loading: true });
updateStudent(match.params.studentId, user._id, token, formData).then(
  (data) => {
    if (data.error) {
      setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
    } else {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        fullName: "",
        admissionNumber: "",
        rollNumber: "",
        age: "",
        email: "",
        faculty: "",
        gender: "",
        loading: false,
        success: true,
      });
    }
  }
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the radio button like below to make it checked while loading from DB.

<input type="radio" name="nee" value="male" checked={stateVar.gender == 'male'} />Male
<input type="radio" name="nee" value="female" checked={stateVar.gender == 'female'} />Female

Comment: I didn't get it .